# How to know which boolean field is true in django

Tags: python, django

I am using python Django.I have three boolean fields in my model. Now i want to write a script which returns all the boolean fields which has TRUE value. Is it possible to know if it is then guide me how to do this?

```
class Job_offer(models.Model):

    min_salary = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Min Salary (per month)")
    max_salary = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Max Salary (per month)")

    travel_allowance = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    variable_pay = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pf_esic = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="PF/ESIC provided?")
```

Comment: i have edited @ozgur , please check

Comment: entire model please!

Comment: @ozgur Now please check.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you can use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to build a query for objects where any of the boolean fields are True.

```
from django.db.models import Q
Job_offer.objects.filter(
    Q(travel_allowance=True) |
    Q(variable_pay=True) |
    Q(pf_esic=True)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your question was written correctly, maybe you should explain why do you need this so we can understand a little more your problem.

If I understood correctly you want a query like this in a function.

```
def positive_jobs(self):
    return Job_offer.objects.filter(travel_allowance=True, variable_pay=True, pf_esic=True)
```